# A Proof that Orthogonal Complement is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products

So our professor asked us to prove that considering any subspace $S$ of a vector space $V$, the orthogonal complement $S^{\perp}$ is unique. I have devised a proof and I am not sure whether this works. Please check my proof, which is as follows:

> Consider that there are at least two different orthogonal complements $S^{\perp}_1$ and $S^{\perp}_2$ of $S$. Then because we know that $V=S+S^{\perp}_1=S+S^{\perp}_2$ and the sum is direct, $v=s_1+s^{\perp}_1=s_2+s^{\perp}_2$ where $v\in V,s_1,s_2\in S,s^{\perp}_1\in S^{\perp}_1,s^{\perp}_2\in S^{\perp}_2$. $v$ is arbitrary.
>
> So that gives $s^{\perp}_1=(s_2-s_1)+s^{\perp}_2$. Now observing that the inner product $\left<s^{\perp}_1,s_2-s_1\right>=0$ by orthogonality, and then putting in $s^{\perp}_1=(s_2-s_1)+s^{\perp}_2$ in this inner product, we obtain $||s_2-s_1||=0$ implying that $s_1=s_2=s$(say).
>
> So we have $v=s+s^{\perp}_1=s+s^{\perp}_2$ implying $s^{\perp}_1=s^{\perp}_2$. But $s^{\perp}_1\in S^{\perp}_1$ and $s^{\perp}_2\in S^{\perp}_2$ implying that $S^{\perp}_1\subset S^{\perp}_2$ and $S^{\perp}_2\subset S^{\perp}_1$ as $v$ was arbitrary (and hence $s^{\perp}_1,s^{\perp}_2$ are arbitrary). This shows that $S^{\perp}_1=S^{\perp}_2$ and the result is proved. Further, this shows that for any vector $v=s+s^{\perp}$ the complement $s^{\perp}$ is also unique.

Comment: I think what you mean is: let $V\in V$ be arbitrary.  Then *there exist* $s_1,s_2\in S,s_1^\perp\in S_1^\perp,s_2^\perp\in S_2^\perp$ such that $v=s_1+s_1^\perp=s_2+s_2^\perp$.  Adding '$v$ is arbitrary' to the end of the sentence does not make this clear.  You need to introduce $v$ properly before you start using it.

Comment: Another point - $v$ may be arbitrary, but $s_1^\perp,s_2^\perp$ are not - they depend on the choice of $v$.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I start with a basis?

Comment: What is *your professor's* definition of orthogonal complement? I guess: $V=S+S^\perp$ But that is not unique: $\mathbb{R}^2=\lambda(1,0)+\kappa(0,1)=\lambda(1,0)+\kappa'(1,1)$ Giving more constraint on this definition is just the hammer-method. The usual definition is instead: $A^\perp:=\{v:v\perp A\}$ Closed subspaces then satisfy: $V=S+S^\perp$ Then uniqueness is not a question anymore.

Comment: @Freeze_S the orthogonal complement as defined by my professor is exactly your definition of $A$. Why then is uniqueness not a problem?

Comment: Another much less prominent question fairly of interest: $U\perp U':V=U\oplus U'\implies U'=U^\perp, U=U'^\perp$

Comment: Because the definition is not ill-defined?!

Comment: And yet another question of practical interest: $A^\perp=A'^\perp\implies\overline{\langle A\rangle}=\overline{\langle A'\rangle}$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assume $$S\oplus T_1=S\oplus T_2=V\ ,\tag{1}$$
where both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are orthogonal to $S$. Consider a $t\in T_1\ (\subset V)$. Then $V=S\oplus T_2$ implies that there is an $s\in S$ and a $t'\in T_2$
with
$$t=s+t'\ .$$
Taking the scalar product with $s$ on both sides one immediately gets $\langle s,s\rangle=0$, or $s=0$. This implies $t=t'\in T_2$, and as $t\in T_1$ was arbitrary we conclude that $T_1\subset T_2$. By symmetry, the reverse inclusion holds as well, whence $T_1=T_2$.

Note that this proof works even in the infinite-dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

Towards the end of the proof, you show that $s_1^\perp=s_2^\perp$, and then claim that, *since $s_1^\perp,s_2^\perp$ are arbitrary, you can say that $S_1^\perp\subset S_2^\perp$ and $S_2^\perp\subset S_1^\perp$.  This is incorrect.  You cannot immediately assume that $s_1,s_2$ are arbitrary elements of $S_1,S_2$: they have been carefully chosen at the beginning so that $s_1+s_1^\perp=s_2+s_2^\perp=v$, where $v$ is an arbitrarily chosen vector that never ends up getting used.

You've got the right idea: you want to show that an arbitrary element of $S_1^\perp$ is contained in $S_2^\perp$ and vice versa.  But tying them down with a vector $v$ at the beginning isn't going to help you.  Moreover, you never use $v$, only $s_1,s_2,s_1^\perp,s_2^\perp$.  Can you think of a way you might fix this without introducing the arbitrary vector $v$?

Comment: Maybe start with bases of $S^{\perp}_1$ and $S^{\perp}_2$ and then by a linear combination of basis elements, I obtain an arbitrary element of $S^{\perp}_1$. Then maybe I have to show that this arbitrary element of $S^{\perp}_1$ is also a linear combination of the basis elements of $S^{\perp}_2$. Will this idea work?

Comment: Mmm...possibly, but what do you gain by passing to bases of $S_1^\perp,S_2^\perp$?

Comment: Ok, how about this: I start with an orthonormal basis of $V$ from which I can extricate a basis of $S$. The other basis elements will form a basis for $S^{\perp}_1$. Similarly I take ANOTHER orthonormal basis of $V$, extricate a basis of $S$ and am left with a basis of $S^{\perp}_2$. Then if I can show that the spans of the bases of $S^{\perp}_1$ and $S^{\perp}_2$ match then possibly I will be done.

Comment: OK, but why are you taking bases at all?  Have you given up on trying to do the problem without?

Comment: Any hint? Maybe I start with arbitrary element of $S^{\perp}_1$ and show it is in $S^{\perp}_2$. But how to do this without a suitable construction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ean by 'suitable construction'.  That's a good idea.  Why not see where it takes you?

Comment: Alright, tomorrow, this time, please check Math.Stackexchange for this question. I will think hard on this problem and possibly submit a solution and you will judge if it is right or wrong. You helped me a lot in showing my method is not correct. But one question: when I say $s^{\perp}_1=s^{\perp}_2$ am I not implying that for a vector $v$ there can be a unique $s$ and $s^{\perp}$? Actually I am a beginner at this.

Comment: You have shown that there are unique $s and s^\perp$ for a vector $v$.  But that doesn't answer the question on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S\subset V$ and suppose $S_1^\perp,S_2^\perp$ are two different orthogonal complements for $S$.  Let $s_1^\perp\in S_1^\perp$.  Then $s_1^\perp\in V$, so we can write $s_1^\perp=s+s_2^\perp$, where $s\in S,s_2^\perp\in S_2^\perp$.  Now observe that $s=s_1^\perp-s_2^\perp$, so $\|s\|^2=\left<s,s_1^\perp-s_2^\perp\right>=\left<s,s_1^\perp\right>-\left<s,s_2^\perp\right>=0-0=0$.  Therefore, $s=0$ and so $s_1^\perp=s_2^\perp\in S_2^\perp$.  Since $s_1^\perp$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $S_1^\perp\subset S_2^\perp$.  An identical argument tells us that $S_2^\perp\subset S_1^\perp$.  We conclude that $S_1^\perp=S_2^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**

> At the very heart your problematic is about:
>   $$V=U\oplus_\perp U'\implies U'=U^\perp$$

On the one hand, one has:
$$U\perp U':\quad u'\in U'\implies u'\perp U\implies u'\in U^\perp$$

On the other hand, one has:
$$V=U\oplus U':\quad u^\perp\in U^\perp\implies 0=\langle u,u^\perp\rangle=\langle u,u+u'\rangle=\|u\|^2\implies u^\perp\in U'$$

*(That unveils orthogonal decompositions as orthogonal complements!)*

**Corollary**

Especially, your assertion is a corollary then as:
$$V=U\oplus_\perp U'=U\oplus_\perp U''\implies U'=U^\perp=U''$$
*(Note that uniqueness of the orthogonal complement is not an issue.)*