# Determine the orthogonal complement of x in span [p1, p2, p3].

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let vectors P1, P2, and P3 be defined as follows:

P1 = [1 2 3 4] $^{T}$, P2 = [4 -2 -6 -7]$^{T}$, and P3 = [3 4 -2 1]$^{T}$

Let $x = [1 \, 2\, 3\, 7]^{T}$

This question is compromised into two parts:

a. Determine the closest vector $\hat{x}$ in span [P1, P2, P3].

b. Determine the orthogonal complement of x in span[P1, P2, P3].

Part a. is simply the projection x onto the subspace spanned by those vectors: $A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}x$. However, I am unsure about part b. I know that $x - \dot{x}$ is the orthogonal complement to the subspace spanned by [P1, P2, P3], but how do I find the orthogonal complement of x $\textbf{in}$ span [P1, P2, P3]?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695545/721644)

Comment: You only have to take $x$ and normalize it and apply _Gram-Schmidt_ further.

Comment: [The orthogonal complement is unique](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1106649/721644), so it should be straight-forward.